# Twisted Python IRC bot set channel modes

Tags: python, twisted, irc, bots

How can I use Twisted Python to automatically voice users in my channel and do other channel operator commands (and even network oper commands?  like handling vhost requests, etc.)?

Comment: I think you can be more specific, are you looking for a library? twistedmatrix.com has a list of them which may be suitable for your task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mode function of the IRCClient to set channel and user modes:
http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/11.0.0/api/twisted.words.protocols.irc.IRCClient.html#mode

If you follow the guide at http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/writing-markov-chain-irc-bot-twisted-and-python/ then you could create a privmsg function:

```
def privmsg(self, user, channel, msg):
    if msg == "!voiceme":
        self.mode(self.factory.channel, True, 'v', user=user)
```